# Django, ReactJS, Webpack hot reload

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I've been trying to set up a React component inside Django with the help of Webpack 4.

To get me starting I went through and read:

- [Using Webpack transparently with Django + hot reloading React components as a bonus](https://owais.lone.pw/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/)
- [Tutorial: Django REST with React (Django 2.0 and a sprinkle of testing)](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/)

Both these walkthroughs are great. At last, I got it almost working by following the second link even though I use Django 1.11.

The problem I had after following the second link was that hot reloading does not work when using a `webpack-dev-server`. The problem is that Django cannot read the output file of the `webpack-dev-server` (gives 404 error) while the `main.js` can be read. I've read that the `dev-server` files do only live in memory by default.

To overcome the issue with error 404 on the hot reload files I installed the package `write-file-webpack-plugin` to write out the file each reloads. Then changed the `webpack-config.js` to (I deleted some lines to keep it shorter....):

```
var path = require('path');
//webpack is not needed since I removed it from plugins
//const webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var WriteFilePlugin =require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  entry: [
          './frontend/src/index',
          ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/static/frontend'),
    // Changing the name from "[name]-[hash].js" to not get 1000 files in the static folder.
    filename: 'hotreloadfile.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    //This line writes the file on each hot reload
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    //This can be removed.
    //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
  ],
  mode:'development',
};
```

in my `package.json` I have the follow line among the script tag:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js",
```

And in Django I installed `webpack-loader` with the following lines in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'frontend/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json')
        }
}
```

Finally, in my root component called `index.js`, I do not need the  `module.hot.accept();` line

Do you see any drawbacks to this approach? Except that I had to install another package?

Why didn't I get it to work with `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()`?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ? @simon

Comment: Yes I managed to resolve the issue by the procedure above. Don't know if it works still but gets some upvotes now and then so the method appears to work still.

Comment: @GwynBleidD there is no answer within the question.. They are asking if their approach is alright and why `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` didn't work for them. Both of which a perfectly valid questions. It just so happens that the well researched approach they took to solve the problem is quite helpful to others..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach if you develop frontend in react and backend in django.
I have django server running on port 8000 and react server running on port 3000.

If I add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` line in package.json of react code, localhost:3000 will do hot-reloading while api call goes to localhost:8000.